# Unable to resize filesystem on a raid 5 array "Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition"

Tags: partition, gparted, raid5

Until recently, I was using my raid 5 array with 4 disks but I added two more disks to the array and used the --grow option to actually grow my array. Now I have an array with a 2.7 TiB filesystem and 4.55 TiB of total space. I tried to resize the partition using the GParted Live, but I ran into the "`Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition`" error message. I tried to leave the 1.5 MiB free space on the beginning (which was already there) and also to set "align to" from "MiB" to "none" which worked for others in the past. But neither of those worked for me. GParted doesn't warn me about having a corrupt partition table (which is one possible reason), and I doubt that there would be leftover raid data on the the new disks (another possible reason), since they were individual disks before.

What is the easiest way of resizing the Filesystem in this case?

Comment: What is the result of `fdisk -l`?

Comment: which filesystem? `lsblk`?

Comment: Here are the outputs of [fdisk -l](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HyT53Z8P7f/) and [lsblk](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tWKcVvCkBr/)